# c# text to int64 representation

Tags: c#, byte, int64

I'm trying to convert the `string` `"Eureka"` into its UTF-8 `Int64` representation.

I'm trying the following code :

```
  string message = "Eureka"; // if I use "Eureka\0\0" it works...
  byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

  // this fails because I have 6 bytes, not 8 (as required for Int64)
  Int64 m = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0); 

  byte[] decodeBites = BitConverter.GetBytes(m);

  string decodeMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodeBites);

  if (!decodeMessage.Equals(message)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Message mis-match!!!");
  }
```

Now, because my string is too short, I don't have the right number of bytes and it fails. If I add 2 chars, it works, but then I don't have the desired string in `decodeMessage`... Pretty sure I need some conversion trick to remove the trailing "0" bytes after the conversion, but none of my attempts work. Any help would be much appreciated!!

**UPDATE**
The goal is REALLY to have the integer representation of "Euraka", not "Eureka\0\0" then trim at the end.... The goals is to use the RSA-method on the obtained `Int64`, so at the other end, people won't know they have to trim anything...!

Comment: That isn't ASCII, consider removing that from your question.

Comment: Changed to UTF-8 already...

Comment: If you are going to use `BitConverter.ToInt64` then you have to pad with `0` the bytes array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's *pad* the array with `0` (to ensure the array contain of `8` bytes) and *trim* the string from `\0`:

```
string message = "Eureka"; // if I use "Eureka\0\0" it works...

byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

byte[] pad = new byte[bytes.Length < sizeof(Int64) ? sizeof(Int64) - bytes.Length : 0];

// Concat(new byte[...]) - ensure m contains 8 bytes
Int64 m = BitConverter.ToInt64(
  bytes.Concat(pad).ToArray(), 
  0); 

byte[] decodeBites = BitConverter.GetBytes(m);

// Since we have 8 bytes always, we have to get rid of tail '\0'
string decodeMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodeBites).TrimEnd('\0');

if (!decodeMessage.Equals(message)) {
  Console.WriteLine("Message mis-match!!!");
}
```

**Edit:** Since `Int64` has **8** and `"Eureka"` is encoded in **6** only, will-nilly you have to *get rid of* **2** zero bytes. If you don't want `Trim` you can `Skip` them e.g.

```
byte[] decodeBites = BitConverter
  .GetBytes(m)
  .TakeWhile(b => b != 0) 
  .ToArray(); 

string decodeMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodeBites);
```

Comment: Again, what I am interested in is "what is the int value of bytes" ?? In other words, what is the formulae to convert a `byte[]` to an int value... I'd think something like `sum(256^i*byte[i]`, no??

Comment: Ok, I now got your solution, took me some time - you remove the empty "zero" bytes in the array. Works great, cheers!!